# i have an error in django framework when i am assessing the column's data it does not give me the result as i want to be

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

[i am not able to access the data from the table (title)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXQTZ.png) 
as shown in below this is function course_details from views.py. when i want to access the data of the course table with column title. it does not work peoperly.
def course_details(request, slug):
category = Categories.get_all_category(Categories)

```
course = Course.objects.filter(slug=slug)
if course.exists():
    course.first()
else:
    return redirect('404')

context = {
    'course': course,
    'category': category,
}
return render(request, 'course/course_details.html', context)
```

i want to access the title column's data from course table. but it's not working properly. so, help me to solve this problem. In the picture, you check that {{course.title}} that is write or wrong??

course:- it is model in models.py

class Course(models.Model):
STATUS = {
('PUBLISH', 'PUBLISH'),
('DRAFT', 'DRAFT'),
}

```
featured_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/featured_img', null=True)
featured_video = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
level = models.ForeignKey(Level, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
description = models.TextField()
price = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0)
discount = models.IntegerField(null=True)
slug = models.SlugField(default='', max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS, max_length=100, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    from django.urls import reverse
    return reverse("course_details", kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
slug = slugify(instance.title)
if new_slug is not None:
slug = new_slug
qs = Course.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by('-id')
exists = qs.exists()
if exists:
new_slug = "%s-%s" % (slug, qs.first().id)
return create_slug(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
return slug

def pre_save_post_receiver(instance, *args, **kwargs):
if not instance.slug:
instance.slug = create_slug(instance)

pre_save.connect(pre_save_post_receiver, Course)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: And what is `course`? How do you pass it to the template (show us your view)? What does "it's not working properly" mean?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please response on my query. i need help